# Dysfunctional conditional evaluating page width

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code based on the width of a page. For that, I am using "**window.screen.availWidth**", and then a conditional, as you can see below:

```
 var page_width = window.screen.availWidth;

    if ((930 < page_width) || (page_width <= 1100)) {
        // code...
    }
```

My problem is that the conditional doesn't work, and applies the code regardless of the page width. When I call the variable alone, it gives me the proper value, so I suppose the problem is somewhere in the conditional. Can anyone please shed some light on this? (I am new to Javascript!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because if the first part is false (ie. the page width is less than 930) then the second part must be true.

I think you meant `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 2):

[`screen.availWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.availWidth) returns the width of the user's screen not of the page. You might want to compute the width of the browser window using jQuery like so:

```
$(window).width()
```

Or, depending on what your are doing, you might want to take a look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Wow thank you very much for pointing that out... I had only tested it when my browser was full size, and I never caught that in the documentation... Is there an alternative for finding the correct page width?

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I use media queries most of the time, but I need Javascript/jQuery for this particular case.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure you knew about them. Also, if you want a vanilla javascript solution you might want to use `window.innerWidth`, but it has compatibility issues (IE!). jQuery takes care of that for you, so if you are already using it in your project, I would go for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's an and/or problem.  "If page_width is greater than 930 or the page width is less than or equal to 1100".  I assume you want it to be if page_width is in that range, so just change the or to an and and I think it should work right.